# How to remove Extra height from SVG img

Tags: html, image, css, svg

I have SVG image but It has extra height  I tried to add specific height to parent div  but it didn't work

Example

```
#az_budge_reviews{
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tgm6Y/14946/

How can I remove extra height ?   it work with width  but not the height

Comment: you may need to adjust the viewbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the JavaScript code in this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/knLbjc9a/4/

```
var svg = document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
var bbox = svg.getBBox();
var viewBox = [bbox.x, bbox.y, bbox.width, bbox.height].join(" ");
svg.setAttribute("viewBox", viewBox);
prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", svg.outerHTML);
```

You will get a new SVG code with no extra space on top (the code is in my opinion not clean at all but gives you a good foundation to work on).

In addition you need to remove (or set to `height: auto;`) the height in your css file.